# what is the difference between io.cucumber and info.cukes

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am trying to integrate BDD using Cucumber. But I am really confused what is the difference between **io.cucumber** and **info.cukes** libraries. And which one to use and when.

I tried to read and understand the github [README.md](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) file still can't make heads or tails.

Still further I am not sure what is cucumber-jvm. Why do we need cucumber-junit (can't the standalone junit library suffice).

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Refer to the release notes for more details. - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md.

There has been substantial changes in cucumber 2. Refer to this for more - https://cucumber.io/blog/2017/08/29/announcing-cucumber-jvm-2-0-0

`io.cucumber and info.cukes` are Maven group ids. `info.cukes` was for Cucumber version till **1.2.5**. The latest version are in `io.cucumber` starting from **2.0.0**. There is also a new version 3 with more goodies in github with the master as mentioned in the release notes.

The reason the groupid was changed because gherkin has changed the groupid similarly.

**cucumber-jvm** is the java implementation of Cucumber framework. there are many other implementations in other languages - https://github.com/cucumber.

When you use the `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` on top of the test class, it means that a [specialized runner](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/junit/src/main/java/cucumber/api/junit/Cucumber.java) is being used which will execute the feature files. The default runner of junit will not get you anywhere, though might cough up some exceptions.