# what is the cucumber dependency for @After, and @AfterStep?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

In my `java`, and `maven` project, I need to use `@Before`, `@After`, `@BeforeStep`, and `@AfterStep`.
I have added the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

which supports the

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
```

But, it seems that, it does ***NOT*** include:

```
import cucumber.api.java.AfterStep;
import cucumber.api.java.BeforeStep;
```

***What is the cucumber maven dependency  for @After, and @AfterStep?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That annotation is in [cucumber-java in the current version](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/java/src/main/java/cucumber/api/java/AfterStep.java) but [not in 1.2.5](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/v1.2.5/java/src/main/java/cucumber/api/java). So you could use a [newer `io.cucumber` version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208254/what-is-the-difference-between-io-cucumber-and-info-cukes), [such as](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java/4.2.0/jar)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: if i remove `1.2.5` then when i run my test `CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.`

Comment: That sounds to me like a separate question. Perhaps you could post a separate question with more detail and link back to it here?